# I am getting "unreported exception ioexception; must be kept or declared to be thrown"

Tags: java, regex, exception, try-catch

I am getting the error as "unreported exception ioexception; must be kept or declared to be thrown". It is the error in the path provided or in try - catch block.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class RegexMobileExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(0|9)?[7-9][0-9]{9}");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\CODE\\JAVA_EX\\copy\\output.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\CODE\\JAVA_EX\\copy\\input.txt"));

            //PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

            String line = br.readLine();
            while( line!= null) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                while(m.find()) {
                    pw.println(m.group());
                }

                line = br.readLine();
            }

            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            //br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException obj) {
            System.out.println("errr occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so catch `IOException`, there can be multiple catches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code: `br.readLine();` may throw `IOException`. This is `chacked exception` and compiler force you to process it, that's why you have to add additional `catch` block:

```
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
} catch (FileNotFoundException obj) {
    System.out.println("errr occured");
}
```

to

```
} catch (IOException obj) {
    System.out.println("errr occured");
}
```

Since [IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is a parent of [FileNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html) class, you will handle both kinds of exception.

Also, consider using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which would close your files automatically.